# Add external folder to Spring Boot JAR

Tags: spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Currently creating a Spring Boot Project JAR using following plugin

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>com.test.Application</mainClass>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The JAR gets created correctly. Some classes have dependency on confiuration files in an external folder(Its legacy code) . I need to include this folder with some configuration files in the JAR. Tried different options like , but not able to do it. Can someone please guide here. Thanks

Comment: **In JAR?** Then move it to resources.

Comment: Will adding the folder in resource, include it in the JAR?

Comment: Yes, thats i my point.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. I did not think of this good way. Will try and you know